# Distributing plots across a grid of variable axes length in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have written a [few lines](https://github.com/massimopinto/CalRadDosimetry) of Python 3 code to assist me in the automated analysis of data generated using a technique called calorimetry (for radiation dosimetry). In the enclosed example, the analysis of the input file returned eighth  'heating regions' (top panel), and in each region a pair of linear regressions (black segment, red segment) were made on portions of data to calculate the magnitude of the 'step', relative to the average value of my quantity of interest (the varying *resistance* of a *thermistor*), which is plotted in the bottom panel of the same figure.

[automatic identification of 8 heating regions (top panel) and computed relative step magnitude (bottom panel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXcPy.png)

Results of this type of analysis are summarized in a data frame (a *ndarray* from *numpy* at present) but, ideally, I would hope to produce also a graphical representation with some annotations in each subplot, including information from the corresponding line in the results dataframe:

[Step analysis via a pair of linear regressions and further computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HcAI.png)

The general output would look something like this last figure, with each subplot including the same essential information from the previous individual plot.

[The output is, in this specific case, a grid (2,4) because there were exactly 8 regions to analyse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K3zL.png)

This was created *by hand*, without any iteration, using this portion of code in a Jupyter notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
results_fig = pyplt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
results_grid = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(2, 4, hspace=0.2, wspace=0.3)
results_fig.suptitle("Faceted presentation of calorimetric runs", fontsize=15)

ax1 = results_fig.add_subplot(results_grid[0,0])
ax1.scatter(time,resistance, marker ='o', s=20, c='blue')
ax1.plot(time[x1[0]:xmid[0]], line_pre[0], color='black', linewidth=3.0)
ax1.plot(time[xmid[0]:x4[0]], line_post[0], color='red', linewidth=3.0)
ax1.set_xlim(xlim1[0],xlim2[0])
ax1.set_ylabel("resistance [Ohm]")

# [... continues for each subplot in the grid ... ]
```

Given that the number of 'heating regions' may vary considerably from file to file, i.e. I cannot determine it before analyzing each experimental output datafile, here is my pair of questions:

1. How can I produce a grid of subplots without prior knowledge of how many subplots it will show? One of the dimensions of the grid could be four, as in the example provided here, but the other is unknown. I could iterate over the length of one of the axes of the numpy results array, but then I would need to span over two axes in my plot grid.
2. Without re-inventing the wheel, is there a python module that can assist in this direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you create a grid of n x 4 subplots and iterate over them

```
numplots = 10 # number of plots to create
m = 4         # number of columns
n = int(np.ceil(numplots/4.)) # number of rows

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=n,ncols=m)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2, wspace=0.3)

for data, ax in zip(alldata, axes.flatten()):
    ax.plot(data[0],data[1], color='black')
    # further plotting, label setting etc.

# optionally, remove empty plots from grid
if n*m > numplots:
    for ax in axes.flatten()[numplots:]:
        ax.remove()
        ##or 
        #ax.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Thanks, this template made it nicely. [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/massimopinto/CalRadDosimetry/master/img/faceted_plots_2015_12_22_15_44_20.png) is the resulting figure with a few annotations. The code that generated it, and which was adapted from yours, is in the [.py code here](https://github.com/massimopinto/CalRadDosimetry/blob/master/Core_resistance_analysis.py).